# Windows Azure - run php website

Tags: php, visual-studio, azure

I downloaded and installed:

- visual studio ultimate 2013 (for 30 days)
- runing xampp with mysql datebase and apache server
- windows azure storage emulator
- windows azure compute emulator
- windows azure powerShell
- windows azure cross-platform command line tools
- visual studio express 2012 for web with widnows azure sdk
- windows azure sdk for .NET (vs 2013)
- azurephpsdk.3f.3f.3fnew.exe

I created new project, but there is no "CGI project" anymore, so I chosen "New Project"->"Visual C#"->"Cloud"->"ASP .NET web role". Many tutorials (f.e. "Host Wordpress on Windows Azure: Run PHP applications in Windows Azure") use 1) CGI or 2) it's to hard to understand for me.

What should i do to run simple "`<? echo "Hello World"; ?>`" ? Could someone explain it to me ?

Answer (score 0):

I assume that you want to create a php and mysql website running on azure, so you need to follow this tutorial: http://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/web-sites-php-mysql-deploy-use-git/

Steps:
**1. Create a website in azure** (WEB SITES->NEW->WEB SITE->CUSTOM CREATE). You will have to select "Create a new MySQL database" 
**2. Set up Deployment from source control**.
I believe that you must go with git because is very easy to set. If you are new to git you can go with this tutorial: http://clockwerx.blogspot.ro/2013/04/a-first-time-using-git-with-bitbucket.html.
You will need to create an online repository for your project - I recommend bitbucket - and then fill your online repository informations in the azure section - "Set up Deployment from source control".
**3. Publish your application** 
You will need to create a local repository on your development machine (in xampp/htdocs/project_name - git init).Create your index.php page in the local repository newly created. In your index page put your hello world message. Add your file to the local repository (git add index.php), commit the changes to the repository (git commit -m "Added index.php page") and finally push your changes to the online repository (git push origin master).
If the step two was completely done you should get the hello world message on your azure website.

Comment: I understand but i'm trying to do this on local machine, through visual studio 2013.

Answer (score 0):

You might be missing the PHP Tools for Visual Studio 2013:

http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/8292e47d-8ed2-48cb-9ebd-064e0b7891cf

Comment: you are right, now i can "create project" -> "PHP", but can i do the same thing in cloud ? cause in in the "C#" tab there is "cloud" template, in the php there isn't, can i do both (php and cloud) ?

Comment: Are you trying to create a Cloud Service Web Role or a Web Site?  My guess is that you want to create a standard PHP site so Azure Web Sites would be the service to look for.  Check the PHP doc and tutorials here: http://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/develop/php/